# Syntax highlighting in Vim before and after opening the same file in Xcode

Tags: xcode, vim, syntax-highlighting

When I create a file from within Vim, my syntax (for any language) is correctly highlighted.
Suppose I proceed to open that same file with Xcode, save, and then close the file. When I reopen that same file with vim, filetype is set to "conf".
This occurs consistently, regardless of the true filetype (I typically use php, python, hmtl, javastcript, c, etc.).
Why does vim's evaluation of a file's filetype change, aft*emphasized text*er opening the same file with Xcode?

I'm running Xcode on Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Wile I can't say exactly why it is reverting to the `"conf"` filetype after Xcode saves it, you should be able to force it to whatever you want with a [modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline) for the [filetype](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html).

As an example, you would use

```
"# vim: set filetype=python :"
```

The documentation is not the clearest, but you can wrap the modeline in your target language's commenting symbols (`//`, `/*`, `#`, `<!--`, etc) and it will register.  Check that it loaded the desired filetype with `"set filetype"` (no argument) and it will tell you what is currently used.

You my also want to ensure filetype detection is turned on by putting `"filetype on"` in your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: "filetype on" was already set in my .vimrc. Wrapping the modeline works, but I would rather find the underlying cause of this strange behavior.